# Cant correctly install Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I have a little problem with installing and running Lazarus. I just upgrade ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10. When i had 13.04, I could install lazarus without any problems, but in 13.10 lazarus magically disappeared, and when I tried install it from ubuntu software center, it said something like in my software resources lazarus-ide-0.9.30.4 doesn't exist.

After some research on net i tried delete all files from earlier installations, download deb packages from sourceforge and install them, but when i want to instal fpc-src, error shows up with output:

```
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 239063 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fpc-src (from .../Stiahnut/Lazarus/fpc-src.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/richi/Stiahnut/Lazarus/fpc-src.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fpcsrc/2.6.2/rtl/nativent/tthread.inc', which is also in package fpc-source-2.6.2 2.6.2-5
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/home/richi/Stiahnut/Lazarus/fpc-src.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
```

when i started lazarus, it of course tell me that it cant find fpc compier and fpc sources.

So, please, i really need program for school and i dont wanna reinstall os anymore or something like that :(

(Ubuntu 13.10 64bit)

P.S: I'm not skilled in linux so if u know some commands to fix it just write them for 
copy and paste :)

P.P.S:Sorry for bad English, I'm Slovak xD

P.P.P.S: Thank so much for any answers

**update:** output from  `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc`

```
richi@Richi-Ubuntu:~/lazarus1.0.12$ sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"
rc  account-plugin-generic-oauth              0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1                 amd64        GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon - generic OAuth
rc  appmenu-gtk:amd64                         12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1              amd64        Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  appmenu-gtk3:amd64                        12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1              amd64        Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  fp-compiler-2.6.0                         2.6.0-9                                    amd64        Free Pascal - compiler
rc  fp-utils-2.6.0                            2.6.0-9                                    amd64        Free Pascal - utilities
rc  lazarus-ide-0.9.30.4                      0.9.30.4-4                                 amd64        IDE for Free Pascal - common IDE files
rc  lazarus-ide-1.0.10                        1.0.10+dfsg-1                              amd64        IDE for Free Pascal - common IDE files
rc  lcl-utils-0.9.30.4                        0.9.30.4-4                                 amd64        Lazarus Components Library - command line build tools
rc  lcl-utils-1.0.10                          1.0.10+dfsg-1                              amd64        Lazarus Components Library - command line build tools
rc  libbamf3-1:amd64                          0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1          amd64        Window matching library - shared library
rc  libboost-filesystem1.49.0                 1.49.0-4                                   amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
rc  libboost-signals1.49.0                    1.49.0-4                                   amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++
rc  libboost-system1.49.0                     1.49.0-4                                   amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
rc  libboost-thread1.49.0                     1.49.0-4                                   amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
rc  libbrlapi0.5:amd64                        4.4-8ubuntu4                               amd64        braille display access via BRLTTY - shared library
rc  libcamel-1.2-40                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Evolution MIME message handling library
rc  libcolumbus0-0                            0.4.0daily13.04.16~13.04-0ubuntu1          amd64        error tolerant matching engine - shared library
rc  libdns95                                  1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                 amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libdvbpsi7                                0.2.2-1                                    amd64        library for MPEG TS and DVB PSI tables decoding and generating
rc  libebackend-1.2-5                         3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers
rc  libedata-book-1.2-15                      3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Backend library for evolution address books
rc  libedata-cal-1.2-18                       3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Backend library for evolution calendars
rc  libgc1c3:amd64                            1:7.2d-0ubuntu5                            amd64        conservative garbage collector for C and C++
rc  libgd2-xpm:amd64                          2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6.1ubuntu1                 amd64        GD Graphics Library version 2
rc  libgd2-xpm:i386                           2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6.1ubuntu1                 i386         GD Graphics Library version 2
rc  libgnome-desktop-3-4                      3.6.3-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Utility library for loading .desktop files - runtime files
rc  libgphoto2-2:amd64                        2.4.14-2                                   amd64        gphoto2 digital camera library
rc  libgphoto2-2:i386                         2.4.14-2                                   i386         gphoto2 digital camera library
rc  libgphoto2-port0:amd64                    2.4.14-2                                   amd64        gphoto2 digital camera port library
rc  libgphoto2-port0:i386                     2.4.14-2                                   i386         gphoto2 digital camera port library
rc  libgtksourceview-3.0-0:amd64              3.6.3-0ubuntu1                             amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
rc  libgweather-3-1                           3.6.2-0ubuntu1                             amd64        GWeather shared library
rc  libharfbuzz0:amd64                        0.9.13-1                                   amd64        OpenType text shaping engine
rc  libibus-1.0-0:amd64                       1.4.2-0ubuntu2                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
rc  libical0                                  0.48-2                                     amd64        iCalendar library implementation in C (runtime)
rc  libimobiledevice3                         1.1.4-1ubuntu6.2                           amd64        Library for communicating with the iPhone and iPod Touch
rc  libisc92                                  1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                 amd64        ISC Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libkms1:amd64                             2.4.46-1                                   amd64        Userspace interface to kernel DRM buffer management
rc  libllvm3.2:i386                           1:3.2repack-7ubuntu1                       i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libmikmod2:amd64                          3.1.12-5                                   amd64        Portable sound library
rc  libpackagekit-glib2-14:amd64              0.7.6-3ubuntu1                             amd64        Library for accessing PackageKit using GLib
rc  libpoppler28:amd64                        0.20.5-1ubuntu3                            amd64        PDF rendering library
rc  libraw5:amd64                             0.14.7-0ubuntu1.13.04.2                    amd64        raw image decoder library
rc  librhythmbox-core6                        2.98-0ubuntu5                              amd64        support library for the rhythmbox music player
rc  libsdl-mixer1.2:amd64                     1.2.12-7ubuntu1                            amd64        Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
rc  libsnmp15                                 5.4.3~dfsg-2.7ubuntu1                      amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
rc  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1                       4.2.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Ubuntu One synchronization daemon library
rc  libunity-core-6.0-5                       7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1          amd64        Core library for the Unity interface.
rc  libusb-0.1-4:i386                         2:0.1.12-23.2ubuntu1                       i386         userspace USB programming library
rc  libwayland0:amd64                         1.0.5-0ubuntu1                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - shared libraries
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic              3.8.0-19.30                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic              3.8.0-31.46                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic        3.8.0-19.30                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-31-generic        3.8.0-31.46                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  screen-resolution-extra                   0.15ubuntu1                                all          Extension for the GNOME screen resolution applet
rc  unity-common                              7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1          all          Common files for the Unity interface.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting trouble in installing via Software Center then you can install the latest version by downloading the .deb files. If you want to install the latest version then following way would help you.

**How to install latest Lazarus (1.0.12) via downloading `.deb` files**

- First remove any residual/broken packages of Lazarus if any by executing these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge fpc lazarus
  sudo rm -Rf /usr/lib/fpc
  sudo rm -Rf /usr/lib/lazarus
  sudo rm -Rf /usr/share/fpcsrc
  sudo rm -f ~/.fpc
  sudo rm -Rf ~/.lazarus
  ```
- Now downloading the latest `.deb` files:

  **32-bit version**

  Execute these commands in terminal:

  ```
  mkdir ~/lazarus1.0.12 && cd ~/lazarus1.0.12

  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20i386%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/lazarus_1.0.12-0_i386.deb/download
  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20i386%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/fpc-src_2.6.2-0_i386.deb/download
  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20i386%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/fpc_2.6.2-0_i386.deb/download

  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  **64 Bit Version**

  Execute these commands in terminal:

  ```
  mkdir ~/lazarus1.0.12 && cd ~/lazarus1.0.12

  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/lazarus_1.0.12-0_amd64.deb/download
  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/fpc-src_2.6.2-0_amd64.deb/download
  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.12/fpc_2.6.2-0_amd64.deb/download

  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  **Note**: If it says while installing, some library files missing then you can install that using `sudo apt-get -f install name_of_the_missing_file`

Once installed you can start **lazarus** by executing this command: `startlazarus` or type `startlazarus` after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You'll get **lazarus** icon on dash after a system restart.

Reply if something goes wrong, or you get any error at any command by mentioning the command with the error.

<sub>**Source**: [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/?source=navbar)</sub>

Comment: dpkg: error processing download.1.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fpcsrc/2.6.2/rtl/nativent/tthread.inc', which is also in package fpc-source-2.6.2 2.6.2-5
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
..............................
same error is with download.2.deb but instead of tthread.inc is errores.msg

Comment: Then it is not the problem with the package you are installing.. You may have broken/residual packages which are causing the issue.. Either your **dpkg** is broken or something else. Execute these commands to solve your issue: `sudo apt-get autoremove lazarus fpc && sudo apt-get --purge remove lazarus fpc`, `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`,`sudo reboot`. Then try the steps I mentioned in answer. If still it gives the error then edit your question and post the output of this command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"`. Reply..

Comment: nothing changed, same errors, but when i want install some of the missing file with that command apt-get -f install something, it want from me to run that command without name of package (just apt-get -f install) and that command want install soooo much packages. Should i run it or not?

Comment: OMG! You've a lot of broken packages.. The output you gave is nothing but the broken/residual packages. Yes you've to do if you want to fix your problem. You've to execute every command that I've suggested in previous. Try executing those commands one by one, this time execute this command first: `sudo apt-get update`. Reply.. One question: What did you actually do to your system? :) You've really broken your system..

Comment: Everything was OK before upgrade :(

Comment: Ok don't worry! Try those commands, it should fix your issue.

Comment: everything always end on this: 
Package fp-utils-2.6.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'fp-utils-2.6.0' has no installation candidate

or dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
it will be 20 hours. 20 hours im trying to fix it :D im so lucky :(
Is my system definitely dead? :(

Comment: It is clear that you've broken packages. YOu can try [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) to fix. You can install it by: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` Hope this time you can install it. If you get any problem while installing then post the output in the question.

Comment: Synaptic is installed, but im little bit out. Whot exactly i need install now? :o I have little confusion in head :D :D

Comment: the link I've given above will help you.

Comment: I (i have no idea how) installed everything for lazarus, but when i want compile something or rebuild lazarus its always saying me `Fatal: Can not find unit system used by Lazarus.`

Comment: Try these commands once: `sudo apt-get remove --purge $(sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get dpkg-reconfigure lazarus`, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, `sudo update-initramfs -u`. The last two commands would take some time if executes successfully without any error message..

Comment: There was no errors, but it does not help lazarus, so i get angry, and i tried it all again. Delete lazarus, do that cleaning thinds, this ultrarepairingcommands, attemp to install lazarus. And Again that ..... error `broken pipe` for example for `fpc-src` package. I think that system is **dead** :D thanks to upgrade :)

Comment: **Ok last try**, Since you got all the errors after upgrading your system: try these commands hope it will fix your issue: `sudo apt-get -f update && sudo apt-get -f upgrade`, `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`. Also install [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) by executing: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and check whether you've any broken packages. If it still doesn't help then last option is to re-install your sytem and this time not to play around your system  **:)**

Comment: Thank You very much Saurav! I was looking for solution for 7 months. Now got from here. I just changed the version number to the latest and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue as well, and ended up on this page.  I actually found that having multiple versions of FPC installed messed up my Lazarus resulting in the same error - Can't find unit **contnrs** used by masks.

I tried the solutions on this page, but they didn't work for me.

However, this solution did work: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=16189.0

All I did was delete (actually rename) the fpc.cfg file that was located in my /home/usr/fpc.cfg, as I had a conflicted file located at /etc/fpc.cfg.  The home file will override the etc file.  Just make sure you also have the fpc.cfg file located in the etc directory before deleting the one in your /home/usr/ directory.