# Can't (re)install lazarus

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dpkg, lazarus

I had Lazarus installed (from website, not USC), while upgrading to 13.10 and after that, it posted some error message (which I can't remember) at every start. I decided it shouldn't suffer, so I started reinstalling it, but it didn't work. then I thought I'll start all over, and deleted and purged everything. But it still would not install.

I found a similar, very similar question to mine here: 
[Cant correctly install Lazarus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364003/cant-correctly-install-lazarus)

I tried everything said there:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"
```

returned some packages:

since `sudo apt-get -f` brought up the `apt-get` help message, and sudo `apt-get -f install` did nothing, I went ahead and manually purged every broken package, which seemed to bring me forward, since it removed the entries in `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"`. When I was done I tried it again, since it didn't work I rebooted, no change.

this is the error message I get on the attempt to install the first package (fpc-2.6.2):

```
root@Someone-PC:~# dpkg -i /home/someone/Desktop/fpc_2.6.2-0_amd64\ \(3\).deb 
(Reading database ... 242209 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fpc (from .../fpc_2.6.2-0_amd64 (3).deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/someone/Desktop/fpc_2.6.2-0_amd64 (3).deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/2.6.2/msg/errores.msg', which is also in package fp-compiler-2.6.2 2.6.2-5
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/someone/Desktop/fpc_2.6.2-0_amd64 (3).deb
```

So, how can I fix this? And install Lazarus?

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting packages. The `fp-compiler` package with is also installed, has a file that `fpc` is trying to modify/touch. So either, remove `fp-compiler` or do not install `fpc`.

About how to install lazarus:

You can install lazarus directly from `apt-get` without fiddling around downloading packages manually:

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus-ide
```

But remember, you must remove all your previous attempts to install lazarus:

```
sudo apt-get purge fp-compiler fpc
```