# Cannot install lazarus after fixing broken packages

Tags: dpkg, lazarus

I'm trying to install lazarus from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.0.14/). I had broken packages, but I fixed the problem by removing sources in

```
gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-software-center-catalog). Then I tried to install lazarus again, and the lazarus itself installs, but fpc and fpc-src packages cannot be installed. It gives me this error:

```
Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 374429 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fpc-src (from /tmp/fpc-src_2.6.2-0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /tmp/fpc-src_2.6.2-0_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fpcsrc/2.6.2/rtl/nativent/tthread.inc', which is also in package fpc-source-2.6.2 2.6.2-5
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/tmp/fpc-src_2.6.2-0_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

If I install regular fpc from software center, it deletes lazarus.

And, before I installed lazarus I removed all previous folders including .lazarus folder in home directory, so, when I install regular lazarus, it says that it's installed in software center, but it cannot be found in dash, although .lazarus folder exists.

I have also tried to remove it by using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package) instructions,and reinstall, but the same problem persists. I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369966/cant-reinstall-lazarus), and it didn't help too. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled ubuntu, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `fpc-source-2.6.2` package first to install `fpc-src`. Granted, both package should break each other:

```
sudo apt-get -f remove fpc-source-2.6.2
sudo apt-get install -f fpc-src
```

Please, consider filling a bug report in lazarus.

Comment: The problem is that, when I install normall lazarus from ubuntu software center, it says that it is installed, but i cannot find it in das. When I install new version, I can find it, but it doesn't work because fpc and fpc-src cannot be installed. Please, help me at least to install the old version from software center. That version worked well before update. Thank you!

Comment: "in das"? what is "das"? Exactly what is your problem?

Comment: in dash, mistyped

Comment: Those package are only sources, they are not supposed to appear as menu. "This package contains Free Pascal's own source code. It is meant **to be used by the Lazarus IDE."** So, fire up Lazarus and they will be there.