# Can't upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 E: The package lcl-utils-1.0.10 needs to be reinstalled. but I can't find an archive for it.

Tags: upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my 14.04 Ubuntu version to 16.04, but in the Terminal I got this message:

```
E: The package lcl-utils-1.0.10 needs to be reinstalled, but I
   can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried to remove and reinstall the program Lazarus, but I can't open the Software Center.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reinstall Software center

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> simultaneously to enter terminal.

To uninstall Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
```

To re-install Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center -y
```

---

If this doesn't help then maybe the cache files are corrupted and that's getting in between opening of software center. To regenerate it open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/software-center/xapian
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/format /var/lib/dpkg/info/format.bak
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

To solve the issue with Lazarus [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364027/665251) might help you